# Why "curl -k https://www.google.com" is not work?

Tags: curl, ssl

Environment: macOs + iTerm(has be set https_proxy and http_proxy) + shadowsocks(in auto mode)

why curl -k https://www.google.com (not http) has no effect, while https://www.google.com is ok in google chrome location?

curl -i  http://www.google.com

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 13 Feb 2019 09:02:54 GMT
...
```

curl -k https://www.google.com

```
curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
```

Comment: My understanding of the question: User is able to access the google home page over HTTP but not HTTPS. If that is the case, please respond here, and I'll update your question accordingly.

Comment: 1. I can access  the google home page with  Chrome Browser.  
  
2. I can access  the google home page over http with curl. 
  
3. I can not access  the google home page over https with curl.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding of your question if right, you're facing troubles accessing the Google home page over HTTPS.

Based on the error message you provided, the first thought goes towards you using an old version of OpenSSL which supports only upto SSLv3 or TLSv1, both of which are now deprecated protocols. Try using a newer version of curl and see if it still persists

Comment: curl-config --version  
 ```libcurl 7.54.0```

Comment: Then I have install the curl via brew, it's version 7.64.0. The try outputs is here

 ```/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.64.0/bin/curl -k https://www.google.com```   

```curl: (4) Unsupported proxy 'https://127.0.0.1:1087', libcurl is built without the HTTPS-proxy support.  ```

Comment: Yep. I have used https_proxy with shadowsocks in auto mode.

Comment: Please add this information to the main question. Also, the solution is right there, you need to rebuild curl with proxy support

Comment: Yes. I have add. But the main question error is CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO. So not necessarily "curl is not support https proxy" is the reason. And now I have no condition to try rebuild curl.